# Is there a way of executing multiple environments using wildcards via Newman?

Tags: testing, automation, newman

I am using Newman to automate the running of a Postman collection using Azure Pipelines. Currently, I have 5 different environment files and there will soon be more. What is the best way to run these different files? Each file can be run as a separate task within the pipeline, but I am wondering if there is a way to run all of the files at once in parallel?

I've tried using something like this:
`newman run mycollection.json -e environments/*.json --parallel`
but I'm getting the following error:
`error: could not load environment ENOENT: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

> To run all of the files at once in parallel

When running in Azure pipeline, you could set the environment json file as a variable with all those environment json files name and enable [Multi-job configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#multi-job-configuration) option to run them in parallel.

Creating a variable CUSTOM.ENVIRONMENT_FILE to store the filenames and separate them with comma.

[image]

Reference the variable inside the command as follows

```
newman run sample-collection.json e $ENVIRONMENT_FILE
```

Next, enable the multi-configuration option and enter the Multipliers with CUSTOM.ENVIRONMENT_FILE, then, run your pipeline and all of the files will run in parallel.

[image]

[image]

You need to [buy more parallel jobs for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted#how-do-i-buy-more-parallel-jobs) if you want those files run at the same (Azure DevOps only provides one free job).